# Indexing or filtering Wagtail blog posts by MULTIPLE blog tags

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I created a basic Wagtail blog page using Wagtail's [tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html). However, now I want to create a filter on the blog page that allows me to index blog pages by MULTIPLE blog tags.

Wagtail already comes with Django REST Framework and Django-Taggit. Is there an easy method to creating a filter in models.py and HTML template using the prepackaged dependencies?

If not, what other methods can I use to index Wagtail's blog pages by multiple blog tags?

```
from django.db import models

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase

from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.search import index


class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context


class BlogPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'BlogPage',
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('date'),
            FieldPanel('tags'),
        ], heading="Blog information"),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body'),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
    ]


class BlogTagIndexPage(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):

        # Filter by tag
        tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)

        # Update template context
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context


class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 6):

The url query string parameters might occur more than once. Eg:

https://domain.tld/path/to/your/blog_tag_index_page/?tag=foo&tag=bar&tag=ni

The way to get multiple values form the request is with `request.GET.getlist('tag')`

```
def get_context(self, request): 
    tags = request.GET.getlist('tag')
    blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name__in=tags)

    # Update template context
    context = super().get_context(request)
    context['blogpages'] = blogpages
    return context
```

Next, construct the url in the frontend. Create a from with method get and checkboxes. The checkboxes should all have the same `name="tag"` attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="." method="get">  
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="foo">
      Foo
  </label><br>

  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="bar">
      Bar
  </label><br>

  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="ni">
      Ni
  </label><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you do not want checkboxes you can create some other interface and make Javascript update the url.

Of course, add all_tags to your page context and iterate over all_tags to get the desired html.

```
{% for tag in all_tags %}
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="{{ tag }}">
      {{ tag }}
  </label><br>
{% endfor %}
```

This is untested code, but in theory it should work TM.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you! I have tested your suggestion. It seems fine if each page has its unique set of tags. But if two pages have the same tag and when tag is using to filter, the pages are showing duplicates.

Comment: You can add '.distinct()' to the database query.

Comment: I tried that already and it was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you are not using the rest framework. I'm not sure why you mention that.

Do you want to filter on the front or in the admin?
On the front you can add a button adding ?filter=yyyyy and you can catch that context in the get_context part. There you simple filter on it.

Comment: I am not using rest framework at the moment but was considering it. Someone told me there might be a way to use rest framework to create the filter.

Comment: I want the filter on the front-end AND admin. Can you please elaborate on the ?filter=yyyyy button?

Comment: @Enquest, your answer is not relevant here. I suggest you should hide it unless it may get the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which is using for my website which including the pagination in case your blog index page has many blog posts. I use single tag. In case, the tag is a list, it can be updated accordingly.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models import Subquery
...

    def get_context(self, request):
    # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
    context = super().get_context(request)

    blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')

    tag = request.GET.get('tag', None)
    if tag:
        tag_qs = PostTag.objects.filter(tag__slug__in=[tag])
        blogpages = blogpages.filter(id__in=Subquery(tag_qs.values('content_object_id')))

    cur_page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
    pagination = Paginator(blogpages, per_page=settings.PER_PAGE)
    context['blogpages'] = pagination.page(cur_page)
    return context
```

Here is the template:

```
    <section id="portfolio-details" class="portfolio-details">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row gy-4">
        <h1 >{{ page.title }}</h1>
        <div class="intro">{{ page.intro|richtext }}</div>
        {% for post in blogpages.object_list %}
          <div class="col-4">
            <h2 class="col"><a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
              <div class="col text text-muted d-inline-block">{% trans 'Ngày' %}: {{page.last_published_at|date:'d/m/Y'}} {% trans 'bởi'%}: {{page.owner}}</div>
            {{ post.specific.intro|richtext }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
       <div class="row py-2">
        {% if blogpages.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation blog">
          <ul class="pagination">

            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="?page={%if blogpages.has_previous %}{{blogpages.previous_page_number}}{%else%}{{blogpages.number}}{%endif%}" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">{% trans 'Trước'%}</span>
              </a>
            </li>

            {% for pn in blogpages.paginator.page_range %}
            <li class="page-item {%if pn == cur_page %} active {%endif%}"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{pn}}">{{pn}}</a></li>
            {%endfor%}

            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="?page={%if blogpages.has_next %}{{blogpages.next_page_number}}{%else%}{{blogpages.number}}{%endif%}" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">{% trans 'Kế'%}</span>

              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    {%endif%}
  </div>

</section>
```